# Create a Mail-enabled security groups with Azure AD role assignment?

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, entra-id, security-groups, exchangeonline

I would like to create a Security Group within my firm's 365 Tenant with a group email address and role assignment of "Billing administrator" - i.e. Can perform common billing related tasks like updating payment information.

Is this even possible? I would rather not create a 365 group as I don't like the additional services created (SharePoint site, Teams etc.)

I have tried to go via Exchange admin centre, however, you can't switch on Role assignment there.
I have tried creating the groups within Azure AD, however, you can't create mail-enabled groups there.

The aim is to add the firm's Financial Accountant and Azure Admin to the security group giving both access to any billing-related privilege within Azure and 0365.

With the group's email address I hope to add that to the [Invoice email preference] screen with Azure Cost Management, so they both receive billing alerts and monthly Microsoft invoices.

Comment: I don't think you can assign Azure roles to a mail-enabled security group. Why not just add the users directly as Billing Admins?

Comment: It is the firm's protocol to manage role assignments via groups.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with what joeqwerty has replied above, you cannot assign Billing administrator permission for a mail-enabled security group, since the permission is a Azure AD built-in role. For more details: [Azure AD built-in roles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#billing-administrator)

You could assign the permission for users directly.

Comment: Hi @JoyZhang , thank you for responding. I have to follow the requirements I have been given to manage the role assignments via groups. I will have to use 365 groups in that case. Thank you for confirming it isn't possible via mail-enabled Security Groups. Could you edit your answer to simply state it isn't possible with your reference to ms doc? I will then vote for your response as the answer. The reference to joeqwerty might confuse other readers.